# Can you detect object/file name using Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

My use case is that files will be uploaded to Cloud Storage in different formats. My dataflow pipeline will transform the file/object from csv/xml to json format. Is it possible in Dataflow to determine what is the file format type (i.e. csv or xml)  & then trigger a different logic to process it accordingly? Alternatively, is it possible to determine the file name and then I can parse the suffix to determine file type?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`FileIO.match()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#match--) will return [`ReadableFile`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.ReadableFile.html) objects. If we log one match we can see that the metadata contains the filename in the `resourceId` key-value pair:

> ReadableFile{metadata=Metadata{resourceId=gs://BUCKET_NAME/different/test1.csv,
>   sizeBytes=30, isReadSeekEfficient=true}, compression=UNCOMPRESSED}

With something like the following snippet we can create key-value pairs where the key will be the file format:

```java
PCollection<KV<String, String>> filenames = p.apply("Read files", FileIO.match().filepattern(input))
        .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<ReadableFile, KV<String, String>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void process(ProcessContext c) {
                // we'll output a KV where the file suffix is the key
                String filename = c.element().getMetadata().resourceId().toString();
                c.output(KV.of(filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1), filename));
            }
        }));
```

The filename was retrieved from `ProcessContext.getMetadata().resourceId()`. `input` is the match pattern (i.e. `"gs://BUCKET_NAME/path/to/input/files/folder/*"`)

Then we could process the files differently down the pipeline according to the key. In my example I just write a different string according to data type:

```java
filenames //
.apply("Process according to type", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, String>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        String key = c.element().getKey();
        String value = c.element().getValue();
        if (key.equals("csv")) {c.output("CSV - " + value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));}
        else {c.output("XML - " + value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));}
    }
}))//
.apply(TextIO.write().to(output).withoutSharding());
```

Where the result file would contain something like this in my case:

```
CSV - test1.csv
CSV - test2.csv
XML - test2.xml
XML - test1.xml
CSV - test3.csv
```

Alternatively, you could read them using different match patterns, apply the desired transformations and then flatten the results.

```java
pcl = pcl.and(
                p.apply("Read CSV files", FileIO.match().filepattern(input + "*.csv"))
                        .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                        .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<ReadableFile, KV<String, String>>() {
                            @ProcessElement
                            public void process(ProcessContext c) {
                                c.output(KV.of("csv", c.element().getMetadata().resourceId().toString()));
                            }
                        })))

                .and(
                p.apply("Read XML files", FileIO.match().filepattern(input + "*.xml"))
                        .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                        .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<ReadableFile, KV<String, String>>() {
                            @ProcessElement
                            public void process(ProcessContext c){
                                c.output(KV.of("xml", c.element().getMetadata().resourceId().toString()));
                            }
                        })));

// combine/flatten all the PCollections together
PCollection<KV<String, String>> flattenedPCollection = pcl.apply(Flatten.pCollections());
```

In this case, `input` is the path to the folder containing the files (without `*`)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.